# BitmapFactory.Options.inTempStorage field

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a custom offline map implemented by drawing Bitmap tiles on Canvas. I'm trying to eliminate object creations to reduce GC runs and therefore make the map scrolling smoother.
I see in Allocation Tracker that BitmapFactory.decodeFile(...) always creates byte[16400] object. I thought that setting inTempStorage field of BitmapFactory.Options would change that:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
// ...
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
options.inTempStorage = buffer;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
```

But even with this code I still see decodeFile creating the byte[] array. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 17):

In short, the problem is that when you use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String, Options)` then Android will allocate a 16 kB `BufferedInputStream`, independently of `options.inTempStorage`.

To be more elaborate: `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String, Options)` is a wrapper around `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InputStream, Rect, Options)` that uses a `FileInputStream`. In the implementation of `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InputStream, Rect, Options)`, there is [this code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/21e6e2de1f0062f949fcc52d0b4559dfa3246e0e/graphics/java/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java#L446):

```
public static Bitmap decodeStream(InputStream is, Rect outPadding, Options opts) {
    // ...

    // we need mark/reset to work properly
    if (!is.markSupported()) {
        is = new BufferedInputStream(is, 16 * 1024);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Since `FileInputStream`'s `markSupported()` returns `false`, that means that independently of  `options.inTempStorage`, a `BufferedInputStream` with a 16 kB buffer will be created for you if you use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String, Options)`.

To avoid this 16 kB allocation, you could try to use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InputStream, Rect, Options)` directly with an `InputStream` for which `markSupported()` returns `true`.

I can think of two alternatives that could be worth looking into:

1. Use your own `BufferedInputStream` with a smaller buffer
2. Use `AssetManager.AssetInputStream` as returned by [`AssetManager.open(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29) (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821636/android-load-local-xml-file/7823925#7823925) on how to use it). Its `markSupported()` returns `true`.

The first alternative might not help much, you'll still have a byte[] array allocated, but at least it is under your control. The second option might turn out to be the most fruitful, if your circumstances allows you to use this approach.