# Android load local xml file

Tags: android, eclipse, file, local

I'm working with Eclipse. Does anybody know where this piece of code tries to get the file from?
I've copied my files to the project folder and also the srr/package_path folder.

```java
public String getFromFile(ASerializer aserializer) {
    String data = new String();
    try {
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(aserializer.toLocalResource()));
       FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
        /* Instead of using default, pass in a decoder. */
        data  = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
        stream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        data = "File not found";
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more info on `ASerializer` class

Comment: The serializer only returns the filename. I just don't know where the getFromFile is looking at. What is the defaulr folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code, because of its use of `FileInputStream`, will interpret the file path as a path to a file on the whole Android file system. That is, the file system root will be the root of the file system in which the whole Android system resides rather than somewhere in your application resources.

If you want to load files from your application resources based on file name, you can put the files in the 'assets' directory of your Eclipse application project and then use:

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().getAssets().open("file.xml");
```

to get an `InputStream` of the file to work with. The path given to [AssetManager.open()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29) is relative to the 'assets' directory. You can also organize files in sub directories:

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().getAssets().open("subdirectory/file.xml");
```

Comment: In the assets folder, I had to rename the .xml files to .txt, because the program parses their content, but anyway, that was the place to move them, Thanks!

Comment: please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856407/android-how-to-get-access-to-raw-resources-that-i-put-in-res-folder/2856501#2856501

Answer (score 0):

i think its either the assets folder or the res folder
i would suggest using the DDMS file explorer to find where exactly

in eclipse go to DDMS once in there go to the file explorer tab
you should find your application in data/data/package name  (could be slightly off this is from memory) search the folders within your package name